# Stored Procedure to import text file into Oracle

Tags: oracle, text, import, procedure, sql-loader

I have a text file that I have to check against a master database in Oracle, for duplicates, 3 times a day. I would just create an SSIS package for this in the past, but unfortunately, I'm dealing with Oracle now and I know very little about Oracle. I've been searching for days and the best solution I could come up with is to create a Sql Loader, but I can't figure out how to put that in a stored procedure.

Also, my text file is not formatted, so I have to take the first two fields by position and ignore the rest of the data in that row.

Any suggestions. I'm at a loss and any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
    CREATE TABLE Duplicate_Check 
    (field1 numeric(14), 
    PO numeric (7) Primary Key 
    )

         load data
         infile '\\(file location\.txt'
         into table Duplicate_Check
         (field1 position(1:14),
         PO position(16:22) ) 
        (field1, PO)
```

Comment: External tables are your friends http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the oracle UTL_FILE package to read the file and parse out the data you need to check for duplicates.  It appears you'd only need to read the first two lines.

The file will have to exist on a path accessible by the DB, and the DBA will have to setup access in an ACL.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Demo sử dụng Oracle Objects for OLE (OO4O) với Clasic ASP</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  textarea {
   width: 800px;
   height: 200px
  }
  
  .button {
   width: 120px;
   height: 35px;
   cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  table {
   border: 2px solid #424242;
   border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  
  th, td {
   border: 1px solid #424242;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   padding: 5px;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Demo sử dụng Oracle Objects for OLE (OO4O) với Clasic ASP</h2>
 
 <form action="" method="post">
  <div>
   <h4>Nhập câu lệnh SQL:</h4>
   <textarea name="query">SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE ROWNUM <= 10</textarea>
  <div>
  
  <div>
   <input type="submit" value="Execute SQL" class="button" />
  </div>
 </form>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and/or **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.